# Gap size around electric panel for patching stucco?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, paint, stucco

Just had a new electric panel installed in my house. There’s about 2” of gap between each side of the panel and the stucco. My question is… should I make the gaps on each side bigger to fit in flashing tape, or is the current gap sufficient to put on the flashing tape, and then put new stucco on top?

[image]

Comment: Is it me or does that panel look bent inwards?  I wouldn't be making those gap any bigger.

Comment: @JACK Just you. It’s flat against the wall.

Comment: Do not know about stucco holding over time and not having cracks. A metal frame would look nice.